# Reopen closed tab in adium (hotkey )

Tags: macos, hotkeys, adium

How to reopen closed tab in Adium(version 1.5.10)? I tried arrow top + cmd + T, but it doesn't work, why?
If i click with mouse in menu (File -> Reopen closed window), it works.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, was resolved , thanks to xnyhps in freenode#adium!
I must use shift key instead arrow key.